# Javascript works on Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Why the code below doesn't work on Chrome, however, it does work perfectly on Firefox and Safari? I did try to use $(window).load(function(){
but it still doesn't work. The window function actually doesn't work on the three browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#pro").click(function(){
  $("#div1").show();
  $("#div2").hide();
  $("#div3").hide();
});

$("#two").click(function(){
  $("#div2").show();
  $("#div1").hide();
  $("#div3").hide();
});

$("#third").click(function(){
  $("#div3").show();
  $("#div2").hide();
  $("#div1").hide();
});
$("#one").click(function(){
  $("#div1").show();
  $("#div2").hide();
  $("#div3").hide();
});
});
```

Comment: this is jQuery, right? which version?

Comment: I can't think of any reason that wouldn't work in Chrome but would work in other browsers that isn't just operator error (e.g. by comparing cached, old, broken code in Chrome to working code in another browser). A real [mcve] might help though.

Comment: @Roomy yep, it's actually jquery <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">. But the things is it works on firefox and safari but doesn't work at all on Chrome.